# 'Ctrl+B' functionality through jQuery using input type=button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build an blog writing textbox, in which I am using a div element (contenteditable="true").
I am placing buttons for Bold, Italic,etc at the bottom. I want to trigger 'Ctrl+B' event when clicked on 'Bold' button and 'Ctrl+I' while clicked on 'Italic'. I have written following snippet for this functionality, but I am not getting the expected results.
Can anybody put some thought on this?

```
$('#bold').mousedown(function(){
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.ctrlKey= true;
    e.which = 66; 
    e.keyCode=66;

    $('#displayBox').trigger(e);

    $('#displayBox').focus();
});
$('#bold').mouseup(function(){
    $('#displayBox').focus();

    var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
    e.ctrlKey= false;
    e.which = 66;
    e.keyCode=66;

    $('#displayBox').trigger(e);
});
```

Comment: The listener you're trying to hit may also be looking at _keypress_

Comment: so..How to solve this problem...for now, I am appending html tags in text area, keeping it hidden and showing text in this editable div

Comment: Oh, nevermind I've just read it up and you don't do it like this (unless you want the events for your own custom listeners), writing an answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you make these changes to a *contenteditable* element is via **[`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand)**

```
var box = document.getElementById('displayBox');

document.getElementById('bold').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    box.focus(); // make it the active element so the command is applied to it
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null); // apply command
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u9g3vg7b/)

Comment: document.execCommand is deprecated